# If statement comparing 2 conditions of ints runs as boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, int, boolean, multiple-conditions

My if statement is not working correctly. The purpose is to compare a user given date with the current date, and if both the month and week match (a user's birthday), then getBonus = true. 
However, my if statement is giving me the following error:

bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
first type:  int
second type: int

incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean

Why is my if statement trying to run as a boolean when all of the variables involved are int?

```
public static boolean getBonus ( int Week, int Month, int bMonth, int bWeek 
) {

boolean getBonus = false;

/**************************************************************************
The following statement is used to determine if the user's birthday is 
this week, using the month and week of the month. bMonth/bWeek are generated 
from user input, Month/Week are generated from a real time calendar.
**************************************************************************/

if(bWeek = Week && bMonth = Month)
  {
    getBonus = true;

  }

return getBonus;
}//end class getBonus
```

Comment: `=` vs `==`.............closing as typo

Comment: You can simply `return bWeek == Week && bMonth == Month;` (no need for the local variable `getBonus` of the `if` condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use If Statement as follow

```
if(bWeek == Week && bMonth == Month)
{
     getBonus = true;

 }
```

== is used to compare

= is use to assign value

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 if(bWeek == Week && bMonth == Month)//used to compare 
 // true && true --> true
```

Instead of this

```
 if(bWeek = Week && bMonth = Month)//used to assign
```

Comment: That is better, but it doesn't fix the incompatible types.

Comment: It would surely fix incompatible type problem because this is a comparison which either returns **true** or **false**.